# Google App Engine - Java memory profiling on local dev server

Tags: java, google-app-engine, memory, jetty, profiling

I am trying to determine what part of my app code is needing a large amount of memory when handling client requests.

For this I am using VisualVM and JConsole, in the local development server, but the requests have become pretty complex and it is very hard to track down the memory consumption of the requests, and I have no idea how to proceed.

One request, from start to finish, usually uses: Search API, Entity Low level API (datastore access), Java reflection for entity conversion (low level to java plain objects), GWT RPC. so there are tens or hundreds of classes to look for (my code) at least.

I would like to know:

1. is it ok to make tests in local dev server, since the environment is very different from the one in production mode? I believe it should't be a problem if I know specifically "where /how to look" for memory.
2. what tools or patterns can I use to track down the memory used by one request (and then use it to estimate for N clients running simulateous requests). 
   I believe that indeed the memory needed has become very large, but I need to know how much of my code can I optimize (or where do I have code problems, garbage, libs etc) and at what point should I increase the instance types (to F4) or event switch from standard to flexible environment.
   Also, if there are java tools/APIs to programmatically determine memory consumption, please advise!

Thank you.

Comment: Did you increase JVM memory on development server to try out if that helps?